# Presentation with beamer - How to make graphics and text stick at defined coordintates

Tags: beamer, graphics, presentations, coordinates

I'm new to Latex and right now I'm trying to design my presentation.
However, I don`t know how to be able to be precise about the location of my pictures.
(E.g. in Powerpoint I could just drag them to the position that I want)

Could you please refer to some more info or give me an example?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Section "12.8  Positioning Text and Graphics Absolutely"  of the `beamer` manual mentions the `textpos` package which can be used in combination with `beamer` in order to position images and text boxed relative to the upper left corner of a slide.

Comment: As leandriis pointed out, you can find detailed information in `beamer`'s documentation. However, I would like to add, that it's almost never necessary to position anything absolutely on the page and you should probably not do it.